# how to improve sync core-data to server in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am new to app development with Xcode. I am thinking of improving the speed by saving the data in core-data with one thread and show the data from core-data with an other thread. For sync core-data with server which ways is faster:

1. while data is loaded to memory, I can delete contents in table and insert again from parsed xml in server
2. comparing core-data with data from server row by row. and if that row is not exist (I have guidurl to compare), so it will insert in core data or is there any other suggestions!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, and it works very well. This is also pretty much how Apple does it in its code examples:

Load your feed in the background, i.e. on a different thread. `NSURLConnection` will take care of that for you. For each successfully parsed entity, insert it into the managed object context (core data speak for adding a record). When you are finished parsing - save.

Read the data for your table **exclusively** from what is stored in core data using an `NSFetchedResultsController`. When you are loading in the background, put up an activity view to let users know you are loading. Once loading and parsing is finished, simply send `reloadData` to your table.

Comment: I would disagree with the whole "put up an activity view", that defeats the point of loading in the background.  Let the user view the data while the sync is occurring.  Far better UX.

Comment: thanks for tips, i also agree with Marcus, i can let user view data while i am parsing and saving again. I am thinking to implement like this: while data is loaded in memory and is shown, first i ll parse and insert data from server with a flag(not valid yet) and if insertion is successfull i ll delete the old data and edit the flag to true. do you think all these interactions takes time whil my purpose is speed improvment?

Comment: Perhaps I have not been clear. Putting up an activity view should not block the UI. The offline cached data is available while background reload occurs. The technical setup remains the same.